# C++ IS-A relationship and header file

Tags: c++

I jump from java to C++, while i got some troubles for the IS-A relationship and the header file.

I have 4 class, grandpa, father, child and home with 4 header file and 4 source file.
grandpa(abstract class) -> father -> child, they follow the IS-A relationship.

father will use method which is in home class (which means i had initialized one home instance in father class).
home will also initialize a instance of child.

In the main function, I initialize a instance of home, use the child initialized in home to run method which inherited from father class. When i build the solution, IDE said father  base class is not defined. I'm sure i have include all needed header file for different file.

Finally, i found a solution, i combine the header file of father and child class, and source file also. Then the problem solved.

Can any one tell me what had happend in my previous situation?

```
father.h

# pragma once
#include "home.h" 
class father
{
   public:
      virtual run(){home::instance()->run();};
}

Child.h

# pragma once 
#include "father.h"
class child:public father
{
  public:
     virtual run(){father::run();};
}

home.h

# pragma once
#include "child.h"
class home
{
  public:
    void run(){std::cout<<"test";};
    void run2(){g = new child(); g->run();};
  private:
    Grandapa g;
}
```

Comment: Do you have include guards setup properly in your headers? I you have circular dependencies, you'll need forward declarations. Provide a short sample of your code that resembles the error please.

Comment: I use #pragma once instead of include guards. i think they have the same function.

Comment: So as I guessed, you have a circular dependency. You'll need forward declarations in the headers (`home.h`,`father.h`) and move the code to separate compilation units (where you can use the headers via include).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a ciruclar dependency, `home.h` includes `child.h` which includes `father.h` which includes `home.h`

You need a forward declaration in one of your header file.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/forward-decl.html

Comment: I have done that, combine the father class and child class into one header file. I know we should avoid the cirular dependency appear. However, for some certain situdation, we must have the circular dependency, I want know is this the only solution for this purpose(Can i still put these two class into two different header file).

Comment: @zzyclark Yes you can, but you have to separate the implementation in cpp files so that you can forward declare one of the class in a header file, and only use your includes in your implementation files.
I suggest you search a little more the web about circual dependencies in C++ :)

Answer (score 0):

you were missing the `include` statement, from the child .h file to the father.h file, something like:

```
#include "father.h"
```

Comment: I have done that, I have include every needed headr file

Comment: From the way it looks I can't see any problem in the h files. Are they all in the same directory?